# Как организовать переход при запросе несуществующего домена третьего уровня на страницу...

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, apache2

Как организовать переход при запросе несуществующего домена третьего уровня на страницу с параметром в виде имени этого домена?

Использую следующую конфигурацию Apache для домена (domain.tld.conf в sites-enabled):

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
        ServerName   domain.tld
        ServerAlias  *.domain.tld
        ServerSignature Off
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^username\.ru [NC]
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.domain.tld/$1 [L,R]
        ServerAdmin  "info@domain.tld"
        ServerAdmin  "info@domain.tld"
        AssignUserID username username
        DocumentRoot /home/users/username/domain.tld/www
        VirtualDocumentRoot /home/users/username/domain.tld/%1
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domain.tld.access.log combined
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domain.tld.error.log
ErrorDocument 404 http://school.domain.tld
        ServerSignature On
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes MultiViews ExecCGI
        UseCanonicalName Off
        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
                SSLEngine off
        </IfModule>
        <Directory /home/users/username/domain.tld/www>
        Options +ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
                php_admin_flag engine on
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
                php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/users/username/domain.tld/www/:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                php_admin_flag engine on
                php_admin_flag safe_mode off
                php_admin_value memory_limit 128M
                php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
                php_admin_value post_max_size 32M
                php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/users/username/domain.tld/www:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
                <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
                        SetHandler fcgid-script
                        Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
                </Files>
        </IfModule>
        </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

При переходе параметр $1 не принимает значений. Что я делаю не так?

UPD: Суть в том, что третий уровень организован без добавления виртуального сервера (vhost_alias) и VirtualDocumentRoot принимает значение с параметром %1 (имя домена 3 уровня) — /home/users/username/domain.tld/%1

Достаточно добавить папку subdomain и subdomain.domain.tld будет готов без перезагрузки апача.

А вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы при запросе wrong.domain.tld (папка wrong не существует) происходила переадресация на http://domain.tld?from=wrong

Comment: @densmith, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1. В ErrorDocement нельзя передать параметр в том виде, в котором вы хотите. Но зато можно присмотреться к `$_SERVER` (на примере PHP) и найти там `REDIRECT_URL`, который как раз и содержит нужный нам параметр. Также есть и `REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING"` - тоже весьма информативный.
2. Как я решил вашу задачу (универсальность и 100% обработку всех вариантов не гарантирую):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName domain.tld
   ServerAlias *.domain.tld
   DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.tld/html
   <Directory /var/www/domain.tld/html>
       AllowOverride All
       Options  +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -Indexes Includes
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/www/domain.tld/log/error.log
   CustomLog /var/www/domain.tld/log/access.log combined

   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)domain.tld$ [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain.tld$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.tld/%1 [L,R]
   ErrorDocument 404 /e.php?e=404

   RewriteLogLevel 9
   RewriteLog /var/www/domain.tld//log/rewrite.log
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за развернутый ответ. Сейчас попробую применить

Comment: К сожалению, не подошло. Выложил полную версию файла domain.tld.conf из /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Суть в том, что третий уровень организован без добавления виртуального сервера (vhost_alias) и VirtualDocumentRoot принимает значение с параметром %1 (имя домена 3 уровня) — /home/users/username/domain.tld/%1

Достаточно добавить папку subdomain и subdomain.domain.tld будет готов без перезагрузки апача.

А вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы при запросе wrong.domain.tld (папка wrong не существует) происходила переадресация на http://domain.tld?from=wrong

Comment: а ДНС куда нас ведет? на этот-же сервер? То-есть запросы wrong.domain.tld доходят до вашего сервера?

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/admin/1106770

Comment: в DNS имеется запись * IN A IP

По умолчанию вронги доходят и отзываются 404 ошибкой апача: 
    Not Found
    The requested URL / was not found on this server.
    Apache Server at wrong.domain.tld Port 80

Comment: Самое неприятное, что весь $_SERVER не содержит никакой информации о запрашиваемом неверном поддомене после 404 переадресации. Может, есть возможность как-то туда помещать параметр, так это вообще все решит

Comment: ну...
всю малину портит VirtualDocumentRoot.
Я сейчас попробовал его применить - вообще ерунда какая-то получается. Попробуйте его убрать.